# Obtaining list (or set) of unique values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

I am wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic way to do the following. Suppose I have a nested dictionary:

```
orders = {'peter': {'food': 'pizza', 'drink': 'soda'}, 'paul': {'food': 'taco', 'drink': 'soda'},'mary': {'food': 'pizza', 'drink': 'water'}}
```

and I want to obtain a list containing the unique 'food' items for each person, I.e. `['pizza', 'taco']`

is this the easiest way to do it?

```
foodList = []
for i in orders.keys():
    foodList.append(orders[i]['food'])
s = set(foodList)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

```
>>> {orders[i]['food'] for i in orders}
{'pizza', 'taco'}
```

If the values for `food` are a list or a tuple you can use a nested loop in the set comprehension.

```
>>> orders = {'peter': {'food': ['pizza','fries'], 'drink': 'soda'}, 'paul': {'food': ['taco'], 'drink': 'soda'}}
>>> {j for i in orders for j in orders[i]['food']}
{'pizza', 'taco', 'fries'}
```

---

You can even use [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) as mentioned by [Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110537/obtaining-list-or-set-of-unique-values-in-nested-dictionary/34110559?noredirect=1#comment55972410_34110559).

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter 
>>> set(map(itemgetter("food"), orders.values()))
{'pizza', 'taco'}
```

Similarly if the values for food are a list, you can use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain).

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> set(chain(*map(itemgetter("food"), orders.values())))
{'pizza', 'taco', 'fries'}
```

Comment: thanks! what if the value were a list though instead of a string? is there such a thing as "unique" lists in python?

Comment: @laszlopanaflex Not sure if I understood your problem. But if you want a list, change the `{` and `}` to `[]`. It is called a list comprehension. The set is one datastructure where the values are unique, lists aren't. Also see [How do you remove duplicates from a list in Python whilst preserving order?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/480214). Hope it helps.

Comment: If you get a list of food instead of a single food: `set(reduce(lambda x,y:x + y, [orders[i]['food'] for i in orders], []))`

Comment: what i meant was, suppose instead of 'pizza' and 'taco' i instead had ['pizza', 'taco'] and ['pizza', 'taco'], i.e. each person wanted both items. so, what i'm wondering is can you obtain the unique lists if you see what i'm saying

Comment: @laszlopanaflex For that you will need to add another level of integration. There you need to add those to the set too.

Comment: Or `set(map(itemgetter("food"), orders.values()))` if you prefer functional

Comment: For bonus points if the values are lists or tuples `set(chain(*map(itemgetter("food"), orders.values())))`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Done. Now feeling hungry after seeing the food :-(

Comment: Just about to watch a movie and pig out myself, I will have some for you too ;)

Comment: Hehe @Padraic Enjoy. I just finished my food now. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use defaultdict- It addresses the list value.

```
>>>import collections
>>>from collections import defaultdict
>>>d =defaultdict(list)
>>>orders = {'paul': {'food': ['taco', ['sugar']], 'drink': 'soda'}, 'peter': {'food': 'pizza', 'drink': 'soda'}, 'mary': {'food': 'pizza', 'drink': 'water'}}

>>>for i in orders:
    d['food'].append(orders[i]['food'])
>>>def flatten(l):#borrowed
    for el in l:
        if isinstance(el, collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(el, basestring):
            for sub in flatten(el):
                yield sub
        else:
            yield el
>>>list(set(flatten(d.values())))
>>>['sugar', 'pizza', 'taco']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get a list of food instead of a single food:

```
set(reduce(lambda x,y:x + y, [orders[i]['food'] for i in orders], []))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values you're collecting are "immutable", you can use a set comprehension to collect the different ones. @BhargavRao already suggested this, but here's a cleaner solution:

```
foods = set( val["food"] for val in orders.values() )
```

You also ask (in a comment) about what to do if the values are lists. If a value is `["pizza", "taco"]`, I assume you want `"pizza"` and `"taco"` in the set, not `["pizza", "taco"]` as an element. It's a bit tricky if *some* elements are lists and some are strings (poor design; it's better to have lists everywhere, even if it's just one element), so I'd do it stepwise, like this:

```
foods = set()
for val in orders.values():
    eat = val["food"]
    if isinstance(eat, str):
        foods.add(eat)      # one item
    else:
        foods.update(eat)   # list or tuple
```